Trouble with wrapping template method with Cython
I wanted to implement a builder which can accept various types of input, so I wrote the following C++ code:
//ElementBuilder.h
namespace DataStructure{

    class ElementBuilder: public std::enable_shared_from_this<ElementBuilder>{
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Element> element;
    public:
        ElementBuilder();

        template <typename T>
        std::shared_ptr<ElementBuilder> add(const T& value);

        std::shared_ptr<Element> build();

    };
    template std::shared_ptr<ElementBuilder> ElementBuilder::add<int>(const int& value);
    template std::shared_ptr<ElementBuilder> ElementBuilder::add<std::string>(const std::string& value);
    template std::shared_ptr<ElementBuilder> ElementBuilder::add<double>(const double& value);
    template std::shared_ptr<ElementBuilder> ElementBuilder::add<std::shared_ptr<Element>>(const std::shared_ptr<Element>& value);

}


I tested the above code in C++ and it works fine. However, when I tried to wrap the C++ code with Cython to use the add function in Python, I encountered issues with wrapping add[shared_ptr] in Cython.
Here is the Cython Code.
cdef extern from "utils/element_builder.h" namespace "DataStructure":
    cdef cppclass _ElementBuilder "DataStructure::ElementBuilder":
        _ElementBuilder()

        # These work well if I compile without add[shared_ptr[_Element]]
        shared_ptr[_ElementBuilder] add[int](int value)
        shared_ptr[_ElementBuilder] add[string](string value)

        # It fails if I try to compile with add[shared_ptr[_Element]]
        shared_ptr[_ElementBuilder] add[shared_ptr[_Element]](shared_ptr[_Element] value)

_Element is the wrapped class of Element.
Maybe I can solve this problem by rewrapping only ElementBuilder::add<std::shared_ptr<Element>> into a new function and then wrapping the new function with Cython. By using this approach, the main reason for using templates in the first place, which is to handle multiple types with a single function, becomes unnecessary. Is there any good solutions to solve above error in a better way?

The C++ code doesn't actually look like real template code in that you're only defining 4 fixed overloads and you're defining them manually. Why not drop the templates (or at very least, just tell Cython about the 4 overloads and not that they're templates)

Thank you for your comment. Since Cython does not support templates well, I manually defined only the specific overloads that will actually be used in Cython.
It is difficult to replace the template with something else because it is used in other C++ code. The only issue when wrapping C++ function with Cython is the 'shared_ptr<_Element>', and I just want to resolve that.
